# Create a sequence in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, sequence

I have a data.table in the following format:

```
dt=data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
 lob=c("A","A","B","B","C","A","B","C","A","A","B"),
 month=c(11,11,12,1,1,11,12,12,11,12,1))
```

The logic is as follows: For a given **id**, if in the same month multiple **lobs** occur, priority should be set based on the order of lob value in the lob column.

FOR EXAMPLE:

If for an ID, in a given month A,A,B,C are present...priority should be 1,1,2,3

If for an ID, in a given month B,B,C are present...priority should be 1,1,2

I want a sequence in the fourth column based on id,lob and month as shown below:

```
id lob month priority
 1   A    11        1
 1   A    11        1
 1   B    12        1
 1   B     1        1
 1   C     1        2
 2   A    11        1
 2   B    12        1
 2   C    12        2
 3   A    11        1
 3   A    12        1
 3   B     1        1
```

Comment: an option is using `rleid`: `dt[, rleid(lob), by=.(id, month)]`

Comment: From the link, I like Matt Dowle's answer: `dt[, g := .GRP, by=.(id, lob, month)][, g := g - first(g) + 1L, by=.(id, month)][]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `match` with `unique` values of `lob`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, priority := match(lob, unique(lob)), by = .(id, month)]

dt
#    id lob month priority
# 1:  1   A    11        1
# 2:  1   A    11        1
# 3:  1   B    12        1
# 4:  1   B     1        1
# 5:  1   C     1        2
# 6:  2   A    11        1
# 7:  2   B    12        1
# 8:  2   C    12        2
# 9:  3   A    11        1
#10:  3   A    12        1
#11:  3   B     1        1
```

---

Using the same logic `dplyr` version

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  mutate(pr = match(lob, unique(lob)))
```

---

Base R version using `ave`

```
dt$priority <- with(dt, ave(lob, id, month, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
```